# New line in databinding android

Tags: android, android-databinding

How can I use newline `\n` in data binding? 
I tried below but it is not working as intended. Any help thanks in advance.

```
android:text="@{data.firstName + `\n` + data.lastName}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\n will work perfectly, but there are some cases where it will not work, just make sure **you have not used** that.

**singleLine**

If you have used `android:singleLine="true"` then it will not work, it won't show text in next line.

**maxLines**

If you have used `android:maxLines="1"`, then it will not work, it won't show text in next line.

Comment: My mistake i used `android:singleLine="true"`